# EmEditorのメモリの容量とマクロの速さ、開ける行数の目安について

Tags: emeditor

EmEditorのメモリの容量とマクロの速さ、開ける行数の目安について

お世話になっております。
現在、Ryzen 7 3700Xのメモリ128ギガ　M.2 NVMe512ギガです。

この容量で開ける行数の大方の目安を教えてください。
だいたい256ギガをメモリにすると1兆行は開けますでしょうか？

私の場合は巨大ファイルはまだですが、将来的には必要になります。
それと数十分かかるマクロ処理があります。
これはEmEditor Professionalでも時間がかかるので数分の1に削ってます。

他のテキストエディタでは画面が上下に動き回って数十時間かかるのがEmEditorでは一切画面は動かず速いので助かってます。

マクロの速さはメモリの容量に影響しますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

物理メモリよりも仮想メモリの容量に依存します。もしメモリ不足のエラーが発生する場合には、Windows の仮想メモリを充分に増やしてみてしてください。マクロの速さはメモリの容量には影響されません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。納得しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。このサイトのベストアンサーの仕組みを理解してませんでした。きょう行いました。認識不足で申し訳ございませんでした。よろしくお願いいたします。